# jq --arg variable used in quoted string within select()

Tags: json, command-line-arguments, jq, string-interpolation

I want to `select()` an object based on a string containing a jq variable (`$ARCH`) using `-arg` jq argument. Here's the use-case while looking for "`/bin/linux/$ARCH/kubeadm`" from Google...

```
# You may need to install `xml2json` IE 
# sudo gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri xml2json and run the script I wrote to do the xml2json:
```

---

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
# Written by Jim Conner
require 'xml2json'

xml = ARGV[0]

begin
  if xml == '-'
    xdata = ARGF.read.chomp
    puts XML2JSON.parse(xdata)
  else
    puts XML2JSON.parse(File.read(file2parse).chomp)
  end
rescue => e
  $stderr.puts 'Unable to comply: %s' % [e.message]
end
```

---

Then run the following:

```
curl -sSL https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/ > /var/tmp/k8s.xml | \
xml2json - | \
jq --arg ARCH amd64 '[.ListBucketResult.Contents[] | select(.Key | contains("/bin/linux/$arch/kubeadm"))]'
```

...which returns an empty set because `jq` doesn't transliterate inside quotes. I know I can get around this by using multiple select/contains() but I'd prefer not to if possible.

`jq` simply may not do it, but if someone knows a way to do it, I'd much appreciate it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jq does support string interpolation, and in your case the string would be:

```
"/bin/linux/\($ARCH)/kubeadm"
```

Notice that this is not a JSON string: the occurrence of `"\("` signals that the string is subject to interpolation.  Very nifty.

(Alternatively, you could of course use string concatenation: 
`"/bin/linux/" + $ARCH + "/kubeadm"`)

Btw, you might wish to avoid `contains` here.  Its semantics is (are?) quite complex and perhaps counter-intuitive.  Consider using `startswith`, `index`, or (for regex matches) `test`.

Comment: Thanks @peak! I appreciate the heads up on `contains()` too. I'll try working with `test()` though I haven't found any decent examples of using `test()` for my use-case yet. I'm digging. Thanks again.

Comment: You can find this in the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) under the heading `String interpolation`.